# Laravel Elixir: How to execute a task only in production mode?

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-5.1, laravel-elixir

I am using a bunch of "console.log" calls for debugging my JS application. However, I'd like to remove these automatically when sending the code to production.

Using a traditional gulpfile, I would use the "gulp-strip-debug" plugin that will be only triggered when I run the "production" main task.

When using Laravel Elixir, though, it's a little bit different. I use the "--production" flag to minimize my assets, but I'd like to execute the strip-debug task afterwards. I could not find how to do that in the Laravel 5.1 documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After checking the `elixir.config` object, it seems that the `--production` flag sets the `elixir.config.production` variable to true.

It is therefore possible to wrap the execution of a specific task in an `if(elixir.config.production)` statement, allowing you to trigger them when the environment is "production" or if you manually specified it by using the `--production` flag from the command line.